Why is there always a weird name displayed for the recycle bin in Windows 11?

Above is the name that appears under the recycle bin when I boot up my pc (21xq12sers1). I tried to correct it but it reverted to the broken name in the next boot.
I looked if any other users have had similar problems and there was nothing close to this issue.

What research have you done and what have you tried? Did you empty your Recycle Bin and see if that fixes things? Look for a file called "desktop.ini" inside the Recycle Bin or on your Desktop, and delete that, and reboot.

Another thing to try to do is delete the recycle bin folder using an elevated command line. Windows should recreate the folder.
